# Why doesn't my instance variable point to a Watir::Browser instance?

Tags: ruby, oop, attr-accessor

I'm really confused about this. I'm using the Ruby class below in an automated test suite:

```
class FlightSearchPage

  attr_accessor :page_title

  def initialize(browser, page)
    @browser      = browser
    @start_url    = page
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    @browser.send sym, *args, &block
  end

  @page_title   = @browser.title

  #def page_title
  #  @browser.title
  #end

end
```

I'm subclassing it with:

```
class BrandFlightsPage < FlightSearchPage


    def initialize(browser, page, brand)
      super(browser, page)
      [...snip...]
    end
end
```

When I instantiate the subclass, passing in @browser, a watir-webdriver object, @browser.title throws:

undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

But if I uncomment the page_title method in FlightSearchPage, it works as expected. I've also tried it with the variable assignment inside the constructor.

I've gone around in circles trying to track this down, but I just can't see it.

Here's the stacktrace:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
/Users/Dazzla/Dropbox/src/Projects/over_the_watir/pages/flight_search_page.rb:13:in `<class:FlightSearchPage>'
/Users/Dazzla/Dropbox/src/Projects/over_the_watir/pages/flight_search_page.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Dazzla/Dropbox/src/Projects/over_the_watir/pages/brand_flight_search_page.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
/Users/Dazzla/Dropbox/src/Projects/over_the_watir/features/step_definitions/steps.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/rb_support/rb_language.rb:129:in `load_code_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:171:in `load_file'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:83:in `block in load_files!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `each'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime/support_code.rb:82:in `load_files!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:175:in `load_step_definitions'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/runtime.rb:40:in `run!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:43:in `execute!'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/lib/cucumber/cli/main.rb:20:in `execute'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/cucumber-1.2.1/bin/cucumber:14:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/cucumber:19:in `load'
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/cucumber:19:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because

```
 attr_accessor :page_title
```

already creates a getter **and** a setter.

i would put this

```
@page_title   = @browser.title
```

inside your initialize method..

```
class FlightSearchPage

  attr_accessor :page_title

  def initialize(browser, page)
    @browser      = browser
    @page_title   = @browser.title
    @start_url    = page
  end

  def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
    @browser.send sym, *args, &block
  end

end
```

or (better) remove the **attr_accessor** and just add a method

```
   class FlightSearchPage

      def initialize(browser, page)
        @browser      = browser
        @start_url    = page
      end

      def method_missing(sym, *args, &block)
        @browser.send sym, *args, &block
      end

      def page_title
        return @browser.title unless @browser
        "browser not set, no title"
      end

    end
```

Instantiating the browser:

This is placed in a file called env.rb which is run before each test:

```
Before do
  @browser = Watir::Browser.new
end
```

It's run in the context of the current instance of cucumber's World

What I don't understand is that all other browser methods are working as expected when implemented with accessors except this one.

Comment: Thanks - I've actually reverted to using a method for now because putting the assignment inside the constructor returns an empty string when @browser.title is called.

Comment: yeah, therefor the better way is the 2nd class. Just check if browser isn't nil. i updated the example.

Comment: Thanks - do you know why the call to Browser#title was yielding an empty string?

Comment: Not really, does the page have a title? maybe its a timing issue?

Comment: Yes, it does - as I say, it works as expected when using the method, but not when implemented as attr_accessor or attr_reader.

Comment: Ah. Before you call FlightSearchPage(), what is the value of browser and title?

Comment: browser is a browser instance - it's a custom Watir:Webdriver object that's instantiated in the env.rb file of a cucumber test suite. browser.title is an empty string until flight_search_page.page_title is called, which fetches the html attribute <title> from the current page. Is it possible that attr_accessor is creating a copy of browser?

Comment: i dont think so, can you post a more complete example? (how to obtain the browser instance, etc.)

Comment: The full source is here, if you have the patience: https://github.com/Dazzla/over-the-watir